# Existence of real valued function continuous at $\mathbb Q$ discontinuous at $\mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Does there exist a real-valued function of a real variable which is continuous at every rational point and discontinuous at every irrational point?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila  Thanks for the link